# Expand lvm volume using all existing free space

Tags: partitioning, installation, lvm

How to expand a volume given the following situation?

Looks like there is enough space on `sda2` but I do not know how to make the volume `centos-root` use it.

```
#> parted /dev/sda print free
Disk /dev/sda: 537GB

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
        32,3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  xfs          boot
 2      525MB   537GB   536GB   primary               lvm
        537GB   537GB   16,9kB           Free Space


#> lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   500G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 499,5G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   8,5G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0     1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

What I've tried so far:

- `resize2fs`
- `lvextend`

However I get the following errors:

```
#> resize2fs -P /dev/sda2
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

#> lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/centos-root 
New size given (10 extents) not larger than existing size (2168 extents)
```

**Update**

With further experimenting, I've found out that I've missed to run `pvresize`, then I could run also `lvextend` successfully:

```
#> pvresize /dev/sda2
  Physical volume "/dev/sda2" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

#> lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/centos-root
  Size of logical volume centos/root changed from <9,47 GiB (2424 extents) to <489,04 GiB (125194 extents).
  Logical volume centos/root successfully resized.
```

Now the output of `lsblk` looks much better:

```
#> lsblk 
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   500G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 499,5G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   489G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0     1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Still, `df -h` shows me the old size and the [scsi rescan manual](https://geekpeek.net/rescan-scsi-bus-on-linux-system/) does not help, neither the official [tool](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1314183).

```
#> df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7,8G   17M  7,8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root  8,5G  2,5G  6,1G  30% /
/dev/sda1                497M  151M  347M  31% /boot
tmpfs                    1,6G     0  1,6G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                    1,6G     0  1,6G   0% /run/user/1013
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the missing step has been to apply `lvresize`:

```
 #> lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/mapper/centos-root
      Size of logical volume centos/root changed from <489,04 GiB (125194 extents) to <498,51 GiB (127618 extents).
  Logical volume centos/root successfully resized.
meta-data=/dev/mapper/centos-root isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=555008 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=2220032, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

`df -h` confirms the desired result. Yeay! happy to see other answers if there have been a more straight-forward way perform this operation.

```
#> df -Ph /dev/mapper/centos-root 
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  499G  2,3G  497G   1% /
```